# Resolve PgAttribute and Where Conditional Clause

Tags: postgresql

### What I'm trying to do:

1. Modular function querying for time-range of any table I specify (pg_attribute as string input)
2. Chain multiple conditions as function inputs in where clause, after ::regclass is called
3. Reference the attrelid = _tablename::regclass in the chained where clauses

   ```
   CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION the_func(
      rngstart timestamptz,
      rngdend timestamptz,
      _tablename VARCHAR(16),
      _id INT
   ) AS $$
      SELECT *
      FROM pg_attribute
      WHERE attrelid = _tablename::regclass
         AND id = _id
         AND time > rngstart
       AND time <= rngend
   $$ LANGUAGE sql STABLE;
   ```

Comment: Do you already know the name of the table and its columns or not?

Comment: Ideally this could be used for multiple tables, but each would have the same column names

Answer (score 1):

You have to write a PL/pgSQL function and use dynamic SQL, something along the lines of

```
BEGIN
   RETURN QUERY EXECUTE format(
         'SELECT ... FROM %I '
         'WHERE id = $1 '
         'AND time > $2 AND time <= $3',
         _tablename::text)
   USING _id, rngstart, rngend;
END;
```